# Capturing entire line syntax plus string output for debugging

Tags: javascript, vue.js, debugging

I have a method that runs in my vue js application

```
  methods: {
     searchFunction(helper) {
        //helper.addFacetRefinement('deal', 'deal').search();
        helper.addFacetRefinement('price_per_night', '>'+parseInt(this.slider_amount)).search();
   },
```

The helper should work if it forms like this

```
helper.addFacetRefinement('price_per_night', '> 100')).search();
```

however, it doesn't and i want to know why. Is there a way i can print the entire line plus the syntax

`helper.addFacetRefinement('price_per_night', '>'+parseInt(this.slider_amount)).search();` and variable values to see how it was formed and know how i can make ammends.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it intended to pass in `helper` as a param to the function?

Comment: Nope. I am calling the helper inside the function.

Comment: Your answer is confusing. Question is: Do you import `helper` somewhere before (like `import helper from ...`) and use it like that, or is `helper` meant to be a variable (or some function related to any given object)? Either way, sharing a bit more of your code might help find us out.

Comment: How, if you wanna https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-helper-js#objects

Comment: My interest is just for debugging, right now i just want to check if my strings are falling in place.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temporary variable for your string generation, then `console.log` it out and use it in your actual search call. Something like

```
let searchCondition = '>' + parseInt(this.slider_amount);
console.log(searchCondition);
helper.addFacetRefinement('price_per_night', searchCondition).search();
```

Since this is the only dynamic part of your search() invocation, this should be sufficient?